# Formatting URL parameters in an NSURL object

Tags: cocoa, nsurl

I want to pass parameters in an NSURL. For example, I have

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demo.digi-corp.com:82/Nilesh/betBuddy/api/getEventsXML.php?sp_ID=2"];
```

where `sp_ID` can be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.
How can i do it? Please help me out.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the method [NSString stringWithFormat:@""] to format your URL string. For example,

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://e.com/?var=%d", 2]];
```

If you look in the documentation for string format specifiers you can find out exactly what characters to use for each type of replacement (integer, double, object, etc).